# Storyboard segue sometimes places my viewcontroller partially off the screen

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, uistoryboard, uistoryboardsegue

In my iPad app, two testers out of ten have reported an issue that I cannot duplicate on iOS 6.1.2 (iPad and Simulator).  My testers are all on 6.0.1.  This problem only happens about 10% of the time, and seems to happen more when the app has just come back from the background.

The problem is that when a certain view controller is modally presented, using storyboard segues, sometimes, it is not centered on the screen.  At those times, it almost always seems to be centered at (0,0):

[image: This is what it looks like.]

Now, I don't actually have any code that positions the view controller.  I rely on the StoryBoard Segue to position and display it.  The attributes for that segue are:

- Style: Modal
- Presentation: Form Sheet
- Transition: Cross Dissolve
- Animates: yes

(These are set in IB, not in code).

The part of my code that invokes this viewcontroller is:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UISplitViewController *split =  ((CVAppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate]).splitViewController;
    UINavigationController *navController = split.viewControllers[1];
    NSInteger row = [self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow].row;
    if (row < [((CVAppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate]).products count])
        [navController.viewControllers[0] performSegueWithIdentifier:@"ShowPicker" sender:@(row)];
    [_popover dismissPopoverAnimated:YES];

}
```

One last bit of data which might help is that this viewcontroller is invoked from a tableviewcontroller that is itself a popover and is being dismissed as this new viewcontroller is being displayed.

I've run out of ideas as to why I have never seen this issue, yet a couple of others see it once a day or so (I am nowhere near them so I can't debug in person).  I'm thinking that it may be the iOS version number, or maybe they have the orientation of the iPad in portrait, and since my app is written for only landscape orientation, it makes a difference what orientation the iPad has or had prior to invoking this view or bringing the app from the background...

Any ideas would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it.  This occurs if the segue is triggered when there is a keyboard on the screen.  The keyboard is attached to an editable item on the left-side view controller.  So when the segue triggers, the new view controller gets positioned on the left view controller, and pushed up to account for the keyboard - which has already been dismissed since the active text item is no longer active.